# Call JSON method in asp.net mvc without page refresh?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Here is my JSON method in controller

```
   public JsonResult GetNotificationForAll()
    {
        Int64 userid = Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserID"]);

        string searchcriteria = string.Format("N.notificationfor ={0}", 1);


        PODService.Notification[] notification = service.GetNotificationBySearchCriteria(searchcriteria);
        return Json(notification, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is my script code for JSON method:

```
    var URL6 = "/Home/GetNotificationForAll";
    $.getJSON(URL6, "", function (data) {
        var x = { "padding-left": "10px" };
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $("<td>"
                        + value["Notification_Name"]
                        + "</td>")
                        .appendTo("#Allnotification").css(x);
        });

    });
```

Here is my view:

```
<div id="Allnotification" style="color:White;float:left;margin-left:10px"> </div>
```

I want to show data without page refresh.

Comment: Are you sure that your view code is complete?

Comment: no,i had written this but it is invisible.

Comment: my view code is<div id="Allnotification" style="color:White;float:left;margin-left:10px">
    
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution.

```
       function NotificationForALL() {
          $("#Allnotification").empty();
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
         url: "@Url.Action("GetNotificationForAll", "Home")",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
               var x = { "padding-left": "10px" };
                  $("<td>"
                + element["Notification_Name"]
                + "</td>") .appendTo("#Allnotification").css(x);




                 });
              setTimeout(function(){NotificationForALL();}, 900000);

          }
            });

        }
      NotificationForALL();
```

Hope it will help to someone